# Fully delete Virtual Machine application & associated files

Tags: finder, applications, storage, trash

I have a Virtual Machine app installed on my Mac called UTM. However, I want to fully uninstall/delete it because it's taking up a massive amount of storage. However, I am concerned that if I drag the app into Trash and delete it from Trash, it won't delete all of the files associated with it. Specifically, there are files associated with the UTM app that are stored in `/Users/user/Library/Containers/UTM` that take up around 40gb and I want to make sure these files are deleted as well. I would have tested this by simply putting UTM in the trash and then taking it out again, but I am concerned because I had a similar issue a few years ago with a completely different application and it did not delete the associated files, so I ended up having weird file errors/command missing errors on my Mac and spending many hours of research and consulting before I was finally able to manually delete dozens of files by hand.

I also found this free app called [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) which supposedly solves my issue. Anyone know how thorough/reliable this is? I don't want to end up with any file errors that I explained above.

In this case, I think I will be fine if I just drag/drop the UTM application into Trash, but I want to be cautious this time and ask for advice/reassurance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) worked very well, all the files I was previously talking about were found and I was able to delete them all. The 40gb of storage was moved to **Trash** so it was very effective.

Note: When it gave me a list of files that it found associated with the app, I had to manually check one of the boxes (it was at the very bottom of the list and took up a big portion of storage) and then click the **Delete** button, so make sure you look through and select all the correct files. Otherwise it will probably be a headache to figure out which file was missed.