# How to delete from system files?

Tags: filesystem, monterey

So, I was trying to use ubuntu using UTM; after I was satisfied with its performance, I thought of uninstalling the VMs. Now, the problem is even after deleting from UTM. I still have quite some space which remains unaccounted for, like I should have about 50Gigs more storage as compared to what I currently have.

Can someone suggest where are the files stored so that I can delete those and free up the space?

I am using Apple M1 Macbook Air, and running macOS Monterey (Version 12.4).

Comment: What files you are not being clear. Too see what is on your disk see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space

Comment: Doesn't UTM document where it stores the VM's?

Comment: Specifically to find the VM files in UTM, right click, and there is a show in finder option. It's at ~/Library/Containers/UTM/Data/Documents The delete VM option should be sufficient though. I'd provide an answer but the Q is closed, although your specific question re UTM's storage path isn't answered.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and found a solution for it, follow the [answer in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444367/fully-delete-virtual-machine-application-associated-files). Also, don't unnecessarily pay for any disk-checking apps. [Here is a free and great disk checker app for Mac I have used before](https://www.omnigroup.com/more)

Comment: Appcleaner is fine for removing the whole app and its associated files outside of the package. However the question is asking for the location of the VMs, while no mention is made of deleting the app.

Comment: @mpp I have already deleted the UTM app, just by moving UTM into the trash, but the space didn't recover. Do you think the method you mentioned will still work?

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra Yes, the method I mentioned will work. However, in this case maybe take UTM out of trash and put it back in applications. I'm not sure if you messed up the app/associated files since you deleted UTM already (I was told to not put it in the trash before I used AppCleaner because it may possibly interfere or not work correctly). Give my answer on my post a try and update us if it works.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths [A VM is an associated file to the UTM application](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/2298) (2nd comment on thread)

Comment: @mpp You don't say? ;-) Fully aware, but pointing out that it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, using another app to locate an App's files, when the app itself already offers a mechanism.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Good point, but in this scenario the question-asker already deleted the VM's and still has a lot of his storage filled up and wants to free it up, so I thought using AppCleaner would be appropriate if he wanted to clear all of the storage UTM was taking up.